# How to multiple upload a bulk documents and set 1 time the metadata for all these documents?

Tags: document-library, file-upload

I am using sharepoint 2010. We have a lot of document libraries and a lot of documents which we upload. For example I would like to upload 30 word documents and some metadata columns are the same. So I would like to set 1 time the metadata and click on the upload button. When it is finished, there are 30 word documents with all of them has the metadata I set.

OR

Select 10 documents in a document library. And then I would like to change for all these 10 documents some metadata 1 time.

What is the best practice to do this? Are there some OOTB solutions? Are there some third-party solutions?

Answer (score 5):

You start by setting default values to metadata, the default values for these 30 documents. Then, you upload them and you they have the right metadata.

For the second question, you filter these documents and then you go to datasheet view. Then, you open an xls file and you fill the particular metadata in 30 cells. You copy them (ctrl-c), you go to the datasheet and paste .

This trick with xls, can be done with not just one row - I uploaded 100s of files by setting the metadada to xls and then copy/paste in datasheet view.

3rd party, I 've seen vitro having these webparts, butI haven't use them : http://www.virtosoftware.com/Product/detail/virto-bulk-data-edit-sharepoint

Comment: +1, I think datasheet view is definitely the way to go! Just upload the files and then edit them in datasheet view. And the default values approach is also sort of elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this OOTB and worse if any metadata is mandatory then the files will remain checked out and invisible to other users as there is no initial version.
However you can do this by script
https://spfileupload.codeplex.com/
Other 3rd party tools may be offered - just Google - sharepoint upload multiple documents with metadata

Comment: There are at least 3 ways to set metadata during file upload "OOTB" -- default values, document templates, and workflows. Bulk 'editing' documents can be accomplished using the datasheet view as noted above (although this is limited to the type of fields you can edit).

Comment: John, I've used in choices,dates and also ( I think) in lookup fields. It has potentials

Comment: The types I know have problems are managed metadata and rich text